# faster code to remove first elements from byte array

Tags: c#, algorithm, arrays

So I have a byte array, and I need to remove the first 5 elements from it. Anyway, I looked online and I couldn't find anything that suited what I was looking for. So I made this, and it is horribly slow, in essence, unusable.

```
        private byte[] fR(byte[] tb)
        {
            string b = "";
            byte[] m = new byte[tb.Length - 5];
            for (int a = 5; a < tb.Length; a++)
            {
                b = b + " " + tb.GetValue(a);
            }
            b = b.Remove(0, 1);
            string[] rd = Regex.Split(b, " ");
            for (int c = 0; c < rd.Length; c++)
            {
                byte curr = Convert.ToByte(rd[c]);
                m.SetValue(curr, c);
            }
            return m;
         }
```

What I am asking is, is if there is a way to make this faster/improve. Or another method in which I can remove the first 5 elements from a byte array.

Comment: This seems to be the perfect type of question to post at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Just remove the first 5 bytes from a `byte[]`?

Comment: There is a _lot_ more going on in this code than removing the first five elements from an array. Write down the logic you require, implement it and benchmark it; then improve the parts that are slow.

Comment: Use Linq.... `tb.Skip(5)`

Comment: This is so incredibly inefficient... it's almost masterful.

Comment: @dubstylee not really. "Improve this code for me" questions there are as welcome as "Write this code for me" questions here.

Comment: @CoryNelson This would probably go down well on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: It is a real question :/ Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: @ponoodle There are already answers posted.

Answer (score 14):

Much easier and quicker:

```
byte[] src = ...;
byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length - 5];

Array.Copy(src, 5, dst, 0, dst.Length);
```

This is as fast as you'll be able to get.

If you're using C# 8, you can use ranges to copy a slice of the array very concisely:

```
byte[] src = ...;
byte[] dst = src[5..];
```

LINQ used in other answers, being a bit easier to understand, is what I'd do 90% of the time. But, LINQ has its own overheads especially for simple problems like this, and I'd not use it if performance is critical.

Comment: Alright, thanks Cory. Appreciate

Answer (score 8):

Your code is slow because you're packing the byte array into a string and then unpacking it. Get rid of the string manipulation and it will be fast.

You can use Linq:

```
tb.Skip(5).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
tb.Skip(5).ToArray()
```

?